# web service for recommendation system

Tags: python, database, flask

I'm trying to build a recommendation system with python using `lightfm`  library and an api created with `Flask` framework.
My question is more design related than coding.

The webservice which will be called when a user logs in the website, recieves a json with userid and return a json with userid and 5 product sku to be recommended. 
My desire is to save those recommendations in a DB. I want to do that because in this way I can see and comparing this table with other tables in DB and find out if a user has purchased the product that I recommended.

My concern (maybe it's stupid) is that everything will slow down if I open a connection to DB and write data in it.

Potentially the service can be called between 5k to 7k times per day.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What I've understood from your explanation is that you will be comparing the actual selected data by the user and the ones you recommended. So, considering you are comparing every week once, it won't affect much of your processing.

Answer (score 0):

Your concern is, would everything slow down if a DB connection is opened?

It won't slow down the service. Considering the usage of service of 5k times per day, other major factors are there which will slow the service down or will cause it to stop. Like when the number of users is too high, one python process will fail.

What you need to do here is, use a web application server like Gunicorn or uwsgi [Using Gunicorn with Flask](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04)

This way, what gunicorn does is it starts multiple python processes running flask so it will support a high number of concurrent users.